# editor that allows command line filters

Tags: filter, editor

Does anyone know of an editor that allows custom filters (like perl,python,sh scripts) to be run on the current selection or document?  Something like vim's ability to pipe the buffer through a filter ... but without being vim.  I am on windows7.

Comment: Why not get `vim` for Windows — e.g. from [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

Comment: nothing against it ... just don't have time to learn it.

Comment: I use the Zeus editor and it is scriptable in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). The [plugin page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) might have something that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some text-editor alternatives:

- [XNedit](https://github.com/unixwork/xnedit/issues/34) (look here for [windows support](https://github.com/unixwork/xnedit/issues/34)) and [nedit-dg](https://github.com/eteran/nedit-ng), which are currently maintained and should be also available for windows.
- [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) which can run shell-filters with via the [mini-script plugin](https://plugins.geany.org/geanyminiscript.html).
- [GNU nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) also has the ability to run shell filters (I am not a windows user, but a quick websearch shows there are versions that run on windows).

On the IDEs side, JetBrains's editor can run shell filters through  [Morgan Schweers's "Shell Process"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6001-shell-process) plug-in (where it is available).

There are also a few more alternatives that i list on this answer on [StackExchange Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672935/graphical-text-editor-that-can-filter-text-through-shell-commands/1489159#1489159) (some of them may be also available for windows).